# Fastest method to compare multiple values?

Tags: c#, search

Usually when write compare data code between lists i use this to compare a string or number

```cs
if (list.Contains(searchedvalue)) {
    return true;
}
```

Some case my list has up to few hundreds or even thoundands output value & it took 2-3 seconds to run this alone with a single value. I see that lots of breaking password programs can generate & compare few millions of hash value with input value in a second. How can i fasten the progress like that?

Comment: *a search database code*. That is just C#, and has nothing to do with a database. What about actually searching *the database*?

Comment: Use the database for filter your data and not your code when you have very much data

Comment: `db.DataSet.Any(d => d == searchedValue)` with Linq for example

Comment: Password breaking tools use Rainbow Tables to reverse-approach the hash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q I agree with the other posters: Do not do searching in code. Do as much filtering and processing as possible in the Query itself.  If you retrieve close to 100 fields, you propably retreive way to much data. Add filtering, paging and the like on the Query side.

Comment: @PatrickHofman um, not a actual database, just compare lists to lists

Comment: Your question tells otherwise.

Comment: What is `list`? How is it retrieved? How many rows are in it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman just edit it

Comment: @PatrickHofman i make a big list which created from a file(has a few hundreds thoudsands values) & compare it with a smaller lists. Mostly i used loop to run the code multpple time for each value which obviously really slow. I tried Parallel but i didn't get better

Comment: Load your file into a database table (with bulkcopy method by example if you are on SQL Server or other method to import into your database) and compare into your database. Put your complet code here for look if we can optimize it

Comment: One method might be to sort your two lists and browse through your list as long as one word is less than or equal to another one from a string viewpoint. And keep the position of the last word found to use it on the next word to look for. But the sort is itself expensive sometimes, to test ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures come to the rescue here. In your case, building a structure up front will make further lookups cheap. A HashSet would be useful here, e.g.

```
var set = new HashSet<T>(list);

// repeat
if(set.Contains(searchedvalue)){
    return true
}
```

With sets, you also have set operators to compare two sets of data (e.g union, difference, intersection). It all depends on what you want to do.